# When to use IList or List

Tags: c#, list, ilist

I saw a function like

```
public FuncA(string param1, IList<SqlParameter> sqlParamsList)
```

I wonder why the author was using IList instead of List? Which one is better? I know the difference between them is one is interface, the other one is class. So my final question is when to use which?

Comment: List and IList both provide polymorphic behavior.  IList accomplishes polymorphism with less coupling and it doesn't burnup your single inheritance.

Comment: Even `IList<T>` might be too "restrictive". Most of the time `IEnumerable<T>` would suffice.

Comment: If you got your answer from same site then why are you generate same question... Ha ha ha....

Comment: If you use `IList.Add()` with a plain array, you'll get an exception. I've added an answer about this to the question for which this was a duplicate (I was adding it to this question, but it got closed before I finished writing it)

Answer (score 10):

More than one class can implement the `IList` interface. If you use `IList` you accept any class that implements `IList`.

If you use `List`, you can only pass `List` and derived classes.

Answer (score 2):

Using an interface is generally preferable as it makes the API more flexible for the caller. If your method accepts the interface rather than the concrete implementation, the caller can use whatever type they want (`List`, `Array`, `ImmutableList`...), as long as it implements `IList`.

Comment: `Dictionary` and `HashSet` doesn't implement `IList`

Comment: True. Eyes were reading `IList` but brain was thinking `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

Using an interface is preferred over a concrete type in order to allow a caller to pass in any object that implements the interface. 
Especially in public methods this is good practice.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend towards using the `IList` interface parameter over the concrete implementation, unless there was some reason you absolutely HAD to have the concrete `List` parameter.

By using `IList` instead of `List`, your method can now accept all collection types that implement `IList`, which may or may not be a collection that directly inherits from `List`.  `List` and any of its subclasses implement `IList` as well, so they would also be included in the set of available types your method could use.  Using `IList` in this case allows you to be more flexible.

Also, in unit testing scenarios, `IList` may be easier to mock out, depending on what exactly you're trying to test and what your features your mocking framework has.